# Imports in Java

Tags: java

I have read that unlike C/C++, when we "import" packages they actually don't get added (they get referred instead of getting embedded) to the class file.

What are the performance implications because of this ?

I am curious about overhead (call outs to the referred packages ...etc) that may be incurred because the referred data (from the packages) are not available in the .class itself.

Or the overhead is extremely minimal ?

Comment: The thread you mentioned concluded that the way import works in C/C++ is different Java.This I already know

Comment: When de-compiling a byte code there is no way to determine what the imports were.  The only trace they leave is the line numbers are slightly higher as a result which has no performance impact either.

Comment: WHat many developers from C/C++ find disturbing about Java at first is that performance is not something you a) need to worry about as much b) is something you should only measure in a running program before making a decision, c) cannot do as much about, if it turns out there is an issue (which is rare but frustrating)  Java is designed to be simpler to understand as a language (though the JVM is very complex) and to take away many of the common issues you would worry about in lower level languages.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That could lead to a significant performance hit in all those well known O(2^n) algorithms where n is the line number of the current stack trace.

Comment: @JasonC True, it is the "big picture" optimisations like Big-O which always matter, and Java developers should understand better than they do IMHO.  The very low micro-tuning like, which variables are in which registers which don't matter to Java developers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You somehow managed to turn my snark (which, to clarify, was *not* directed at you or anybody in particular) into a totally valid point. Curses!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no performance hits. It only affects how the compiler resolves types; there are no impacts on the generated byte code or information available at runtime. It is almost exactly equivalent to `using [namespace]` in C++ (where packages are like namespaces).

Like C++, you can also fully qualify a type with its package instead of importing it.

C++:

```
Something::Whatever x = ...;
// or
using namespace Something;
Whatever x = ...;
```

Java:

```
com.something.Whatever x = ...;
// or
import com.something.*;
Whatever x = ...;
```

You can (and should) also import specific type:

C++:

```
using Something::Whatever;
```

Java:

```
import com.something.Whatever;
```

As with C++, classes in the same package can refer to each other without having to qualify the package name.

Note that, unlike C++ `using namespace`, `import` must be at the top of the file. Additionally, package names directly reflect the directory structure of the source relative to the classpath (path separators are replaced with dots); because classes can be dynamically loaded in Java, the package name also specifies where in the file system the class loader looks for the class.

Also, to pick nits, there is no such concept in C.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a performance overhead cost of adding packages. But you should not simply import unnecessary packages in your code. Sometimes there are classes with the same name but in different packages, so you will run into unnecessary problems.

From good coding practice, use only what you need, nothing extra is good. So import classes instead of complete packages.

Almost all the IDEs comes with a feature to organize your imports, so you really don't need to remember the packages and complete path of classes. Simply utilize the IDE features and keep your code clean.

Comment: May I know the reason of negative vote here?

Comment: I would like to know as well, this is a completely valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Java classloader loads a class into memory only when it needs to. It does not load classes into memory after imports, see this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440860/could-extra-imports-in-java-slow-down-code-loading-time) There are no "performance downsides" to this... when a class's bytecode needs to be accessed, the address in memory is almost certainly retrieved in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

import does not have any performance overheads. At least the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) doesn't mention that

> An import declaration makes types or members available by their simple
>   names only within the compilation unit that actually contains the
>   import declaration